# How to set global options for grep to avoid having to use grep -v grep everytime?

Tags: bash, grep

I felt wasting time to always having to add `grep -v grep` everytime I do:

```
ps -ef | grep testapp | grep -v grep
```

Is there a global option so that grep will exclude grep by default?

Comment: @Inian, you misinterpreted my question. I tried environment var `GREP_OPTIONS` and i tried `alias` and neither solved the problem I posted in this question. I don't want to type `grep -v grep` because it wasted precious milliseconds of my fingers. I wanted to know if there is a setting that can make `grep` do what I wanted.

Comment: No need to set options. Just include a small function in your `.bashrc` such as `mygrep() { if [ -z "$1" ] || [ -z "$2" ]; then printf "grep term filename\n" >&2; return 1; fi grep "$1" "$2" | grep -v grep }` then I would set a `alias mgrep=mygrep` below it and then just use `mgrep` in place of `grep`. (you have to resource your `.bashrc` for it to take effect immediately.

Answer (score 1):

You can do :

```
ps -ef | grep "[t]estapp"
```

Reference : https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/library/l-keyc3/#code10

Or if you are interested only in the PID of process then you use [pgrep](https://linux.die.net/man/1/pgrep) command to get the pid :

`pgrep testapp` or `pgrep -f testapp`.

Comment: Note that if the file `testapp` exists in the current directory, the shell glob will expand to `testapp` and you will be no better off than before.  Enclose the pattern in (single) quotes for maximum safety.

Answer (score 0):

I use:

```
ps -ef | grep '[t]estapp'
```

where the trick is to use a regex to avoid the `grep` line of the `ps` output appearing because the `]` means that `testapp` doesn't appear in the `grep` line.